# is this optimization problem linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Is the following problem linear programming? (Bold font = vector)

if not, what kind of problem is it?

The decision variable is lambda and alpha.

Epsilon is constant. q is an input vector, with dimensions 1x8760, where each coloumn is a different value.

[image: Model formulation]

Comment: if $q$ is constant, seems linear to me

Comment: if you can only modify $\lambda_1$, almost everything is constant (including the objective function)

Comment: Please review the question again, I believe there are multiple typos.  Also, state what are the decision variables and what are the constants.

Comment: Everything except epsilon and alpha is vectors.

q is an input vector, with the size 1x8760 (number of hours in a year). q is the amount of consumption in each hour. The value changes for each hour, so that it is fx. 100 in one hour and 400 in the next hour, etc.

Lambda and alpha is the decision variables.